# Ошибка в коде SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Subscriber_idSubscriber)
FROM (
  SELECT idPlan, Communication_idCommunication
  FROM Plan
  WHERE Communication_idCommunication = 1
) AS A
INNER JOIN Subscriptions AS B ON A.Plan_idPlan = B.Plan_idPlan;
```

Что значит? Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.Plan_idPlan' in 'on clause' 0.000 sec Как это исправить?

Comment: А есть такой столбец `idPlan` в таблице `Subscriptions`? Точно есть? Покажите скрипт создания обеих участвующих в запросе таблиц **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Есть, но он называется Plan_idPlan, не заметил. Исправил, но теперь выводит Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.Plan_idPlan' in 'on clause' 0.000 sec

Comment: Исправьте запрос в вопросе на актуальную версию и ошибку в вопросе исправьте

Comment: Исправил запрос и вопрос

Comment: Так в таблице `A` у вас колонка называется `idPlan` же, у вас же там `SELECT idPlan ... FROM Plan` внутри скобок и никаких алиасов для колонки, значит в `A` так же будет называться эта колонка.